# Understanding relation pushout and colimit for category $D=\{a\leftarrow b\rightarrow c\}$

Tags: category-theory

I am reading Homotopy theory and model categories of dwyer came across the following problem:

Let $D$ be the category $\{a\leftarrow b\rightarrow c\}$ plus identity morphisms. Then They state in 2.16 that for a functor $X:D\to C$ the pushout $P$ is the colimit. I wanted to clarify this for understanding of the colimit.

The definition of the colimit I am working with is:
For the functor $F:D\to C$ the colimit is an object $c\in C$ and a natural transformation $t:F\to\Delta(c)$, where $\delta$ is the diagonal funtor (i.e. $\Delta(c):Y\to c$ for all $Y\in D$). Furthermore for every object $x \in C$ there exists a natural transformation $s:F\to\Delta(x)$ and there exists a unique $s':c\to x$ in C such that $\Delta(s')t=s$.

So far I have that by the definition of the Pushout that there is a commutative square and I want to use this square to somehow obtain this natural transformation $t$ but I do not yet see how.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Any commutative square in $C$ is equivalent to a transformation $F\to \Delta(c)$ where $c$ is the object in the lower right corner and where $F\colon D\to C$ is the diagram that is determined by the remaining three objects in the square. The condition that the square is a pushout then corresponds precisely to the condition that this transformation is a colimit.